# How to compute rank of free abelian group quotient subgroup generated by 3 elements

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group, free-abelian-group

Suppose that I have the free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^3$, and I consider a subgroup $H$ which is generated by the elements $(2, 4, 6), (4, 5, 6), (0,4,8)$.  I am trying to compute the rank of the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}^3/H$ and determine the invariant factors of $\mathbb{Z}^3/H$.  I'm really not sure how to go about this problem, but here are my initial thoughts:

If I set $x = (2,4,6), y = (4,5,6)$ and $z = (0,4,8)$ then $H = \{ax + by + cz : a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, in other words, I believe that $H$ is in some sense the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $x,y$ and $z$.  If I consider $x,y$ and $z$ to be column vectors then I would obtain a 3 by 3 matrix, whose row Echelon form would be (after augmenting with the zero column on the right)

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 5 & 4 & 0 \\
6 & 6 & 8 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow_{REF}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & -4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

and the information I can pull from this is that $z$ is a free variable, $3y = 4z$, and $3x = -8z$ (I didn't go into fully reduced row Echelon form since the coefficients attached to $x,y$ and $z$ need to be integers).  So, I think this would mean that the rank of this matrix would be $2$ (since there are two pivot columns), but I'm not sure how this would help me in solving for the rank of $\mathbb{Z}^3/H$ since there are infinite amount of elements in $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

As far as going about trying to find the invariant factors of the quotient group, I'm also unsure of where to start.  Can someone assist me or verify that the first part of my efforts were correct?  References to where I could look in Dummit and Foote would be most helpful.

Comment: Smith Normal Form lets you read off isomorphism type of the quotient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Smith normal form.   You can only add integer multiples of rows and columns to each other.

$$\begin{pmatrix}2\quad 4\quad 0\\4\quad 5\quad 4\\6\quad 6\quad 8\end {pmatrix}\to\begin {pmatrix}2\quad 0\quad 0\\4\quad-3\quad 4\\6\quad-6\quad 8\end {pmatrix}\to \begin {pmatrix}2\quad 0\quad 0\\0\quad-3\quad 4\\0\quad-6\quad 8\end {pmatrix}\to \begin {pmatrix}2\quad 0\quad 0\\0\quad 3\quad 1\\0\quad 0\quad 0\end {pmatrix}\to \begin {pmatrix}2\quad 0\quad 0\\0\quad 1\quad 0\\0\quad 0\quad 0\end{pmatrix}\to \begin {pmatrix}1\quad 0\quad 0\\0\quad 2\quad 0\\0\quad 0\quad 0\end {pmatrix}$$.

We get $\Bbb Z×\Bbb Z_2$,  and the rank is $1$.

Comment: What was the algorithm you used to get to the final matrix?  And are you getting $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ from the fact that the entries along the diagonal are 2 and 1?  Wouldn't the rank of the resulting Smith normal form matrix be 2, since there are 2 pivot columns?

Comment: Like I said,  you can interchange rows and columns and add integer multiples of them to each other.   Yes.  The subgroup you are taking the quotient by apparently has rank $2$.

Comment: I thought that in Smith Normal Form, the entry of the diagonals had to divide one another when moving starting from the top-left entry.  In your final matrix, 2 does not divide 1 - why is this then in Smith Normal Form?

Comment: It might not be,  but it can be put in that form.  So the invariant factors should be $1,2$.  I just stopped when I could see the quotient group.

Comment: I probably should have done one more step.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm still not sure I see how you're doing the last step.  Whenever I try to add integer multiples of rows/columns to the second to last matrix the closest matrix I get is \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: All I did was swap the first two rows, then the first two columns.   You can do that.